# Beginning Java: Utilizing user's input

Tags: java, input, output

I am new to learning Java and in my class i have an assignment ive been struggling with:

You need to create three classes: Duck, Dog, and DuckDogApp. DuckDogApp would use Duck and Dog objects. You may use three separate different files or just one file to contain three classes. Your program:

1.Prompt a user to input “duck” or “dog” from keyboard (ask a question)

2. The output should display “Quack! Quack!” if the user’s input is “duck”, and followed by a new question “dog or duck?” and give a program to end the program
3. If the user chooses to end the program, then game is over.   If the user’s input is “dog”, next prompt should be: “what size is your dog?”
4. if the user’s input is negative or 0, the program would tell the user to enter a correct number: 
   once the user typed in a number and hit enter:

-the output should be “Yip! Yip! Yip!”  if the number is between 1 and 14;

-the output should be “Ruff! Ruff! Ruff!”  if the number is between 15 and 59;

-the output should be “Woof! Woof! Woof!” if the number is more than 60.

5. End of the program
6. If the user input is “dog”, output should follow the step 2.

I am having difficulties understanding what to do next or if what i have is even right. I dont know how to go about utilizing the users input from "what size is your dog" to the bark. This is my first Java class so again, im new- any tips would be greatly appreciated- im having difficulties getting the hang of it. So far this is my code:

```
   import java.util.*;

class Duck{


}

class Dog{
    private int size;
    public int getSize(){
    return size;            
    }
    public void setSize(int n){
        size=n;
    }
     public void bark(){

         if (size>60){
             System.out.println("Woof! Woof!");
         }
         else if (size>14){
             System.out.println("Ruff! Ruff!");
         }
         else{
             System.out.println("Yip! Yip!");
         }

     }
}

 class DogDuckApp{

    public static void main (String[] args)

    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Dog or Duck?");
        String userinput = input.nextLine();


        /*If user inputs dog (disregarding case) it will ask what size the dog is*/

        if("Dog".equalsIgnoreCase(userinput))
        {
            System.out.println("what size is your dog?")


             }
        }




        /*If user inputs duck (disregarding case) it will display Quack! Quack!*/

        if("Duck".equalsIgnoreCase(userinput))

        {
            System.out.println("Quack! Quack!");
        }


    }
 }
```

Comment: What specific issue do you have? Something about what you have tried doesn't work? We will not do the assignment for you but we will answer a specific question

Comment: I would suggest you to explore [while loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) of Java